# ARKit code issue {unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff error: Task failed with exit 1}

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, arkit

I want to learn ARKit. I got apple's sample code and other sample codes in github.

There is a error, Xcode reports:

> /Users/.../ARKitBasics-brwextbgckvaokheuvfoqkacalvx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARKitBasics.app/Frameworks/libswiftARKit.dylib:
>   unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff error: Task failed with exit 1
>   signal 0 {    /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign'
>   'B8FBC6429C19D8DBEDBAC1BD044D6D4D7B68D1CF' '--verbose'
>
> '/Users/.../ARKitBasics-brwextbgckvaokheuvfoqkacalvx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ARKitBasics.app/Frameworks/libswiftARKit.dylib'

I guess it is about `libswiftARKit.dylib` ,I don't know where it is. i found `ARKit.framework`.

Any advice or explanation is welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like this is a code signing problem. ARKit runs only on a device and not in the simulator - do you have a valid dev profile?

Comment: Yes , I was trying run it on my iPhone 6s

Comment: What is the 'yes' for? Yes you have a valid developer profile? Is your code signing resolved?

Comment: 'Yes' is for the hardware. I guess not 'my code signing resolved'. Today it works. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below command:

```
security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k keychainPass keychainPath
```

- `keychainPass` is your keychain password;
- `keychainPath` is the file path of your keychain, normally it is `~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` and `login.keychain-db`
- most answers using this command without `codesign:`, this is the tricky part