# Fastlane gym failed with error only when running over ssh: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 /usr/bin/codesign --force sign '' '--verbose'

Tags: ios, jenkins, keychain, fastlane

When I am running same Fastlane locally from terminal it works fine. But when I run it from Jenkins Pipeline on Mac node which is connected using ssh with username and password.

I started getting this error after I run some security commands to create keychain, find certificates, identity, import certificate and p12 files in keychain

```
*/*.app/Frameworks/libswiftcore.dylib: replacing existing signature
*/*.app/Frameworks/libswiftcore.dylib: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff
error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0
     /usr/bin/codesign --force sign '' '--verbose'
```

I tried after removing all other keychains other than login and system, I also restarted Mac, I am also cleaning before building. I am using separate derived data folder for every build. Still I am getting same error when running using Jenkins Pipeline, my Mac machine is connected to jenkins using ssh.

Comment: What is the lane you are running? What is the complete output you are getting?

Comment: I got this error with gym command, output is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754076/arkit-code-issue-unknown-error-1-ffffffffffffffff-error-task-failed-with-exit/53685103#53685103

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact command you are running and the complete output you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

Started working when removed identity from keychain, added keychain_password parameter in match action.